# Как передать имя выделенного файла в сценарий powershell?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, powershell

Я написал свой сценарий и добавил его в контекстное меню с помощью реестра. Теперь при выделении файла в контекстном меню так же есть и мой сценарий.

Как передать имя выделенного файла в сценарий powershell? Я хочу следующее: выделить файл > вызвать контекстное
меню с помощью ПКМ > вызвать свой сценарий powershell > (и автоматически) передать ему имя/id/object выделенного файла.

Что то вроде "this" в других ЯП.

Comment: Не `%1` случаем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в реестре вы всё сделали правильно, а именно создали необходимый раздел в ветке `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/FOLDER/SHELL` (на всякий случай - [вот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031690/), как это правильно сделать), то всё, что вам остаётся, это powershell использовать встроенную переменную  $args:

то есть вызов в реестре у вас выглядит, допустим, так:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -EP Bypass -File C:\MyPowerShellScripts\script01.ps1 "%1"
```

То в скрипте powershell обращайтесь к встроенной переменной $args - это массив аргументов, переданных вашему скрипту.