# Передача параметра контекстного меню проводника

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

У меня есть приложение, которое добавляет в контекстное меню проводника Windows созданный мною пункт. Вопрос: можно ли каким-либо способом определить имя файла, в котором я открыл данный пункт меню, и, когда нажму на сам пункт, оно бы передавалось, например, в TextEdit моего приложения?

[image: контекстное меню]

Comment: Нужно видеть как зарегистрирован этот пункт в реестре. Если это просто вызов программы, то параметры получаются стандартно посредством доступа к `%1` и т.д.

Comment: Как вы добавили пункт в меню? Как в примерах Delphi через shell extention или просто добавив запись в HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/FOLDER/SHELL?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov просто добавил запись через HKEY_CLASSAS_ROOT

Comment: @pharaxx Тогда, если правильно добавили, то параметр передаётся в ParamStr(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Отвечу, чтобы в будущем можно было ссылаться на данный ответ.*

Вариант регистрации пункта контекстного меню (и реакции на него) через COM/Shell Extention появился в примерах Delphi ещё со времен Borland. Но он несколько громоздок и, чего греха таить, неудобен.
Поэтому большинство предпочитает работать через добавление новой записи в реестре, в ветке `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/FOLDER/SHELL`.

(Здесь тоже есть варианты и возможности серьёзно испортить систему, поэтому обозначу наиболее правильный, на мой взгляд, подход)

1. Мы хотим вставить в контекстное меню Проводника, вызываемое по правой кнопке, действие "Захватить мир" с запуском нашей программы **taketheworld.exe**.
2. Создаёте в данной ветке новый раздел с уникальным названием, например, "TakeOverTheWorld". Ключ по умолчанию - название элемента контекстного меню, которое будет отображаться в проводнике. Например, "Захватить мир".
3. В разделе создаёте подраздел с именем command и ключом по умолчанию, включающим полный путь к **taketheworld.exe**, необходимыми ключами (если нужно, конечно) и передачей параметра, который содержит полный путь к имени файла, на который мы кликнули:
   "N:\MySuperProgs\IamTheGreatVillain\TakeTheWorld.exe" "%1"

Всё. Теперь в вашей вновь откомпилированной программе смело обращайтесь к `ParamStr(1)` - он будет содержать полный путь к имени файла, на котором пользователь кликнул из контекстного меню проводника. Что с ним делать - уже ваша задача.

P.S. Записи в реестр можно вносить любимым компонентом (есть штатные и много сторонних), на более низком уровне или даже вручную.

P.P.S. На всякий случай - вариант содержимого reg-файла, если страшно хочется попробовать, но с работой с реестром пока не ознакомились:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\takeovertheworld]
@="Захватить мир"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\takeovertheworld\command]
@="N:\\MySuperProgs\\IamTheGreatVillain\\taketheworld.exe\"\"%1\"\""
```

(сохранить в файл с расширением .reg и выполнить. Деструктива не несёт. Ничего полезного тоже.)

Comment: `регистрации пункта контекстного меню (и реакции на него) через COM/Shell Extention` - а оно работает в вин10/11 ?

Comment: @ESkri вроде как, - да.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-exts Статья 21 года.  Да и через реестр должно работать.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov подскажите, вот пытаюсь передавать несколько аргументов для программы. Не знаю сколько их может быть. в контекстном меню так записано myprogram.exe "%1". И он создает несколько экземпляров программ, а не один со всеми аргументами. При "%*", всегда получаю "". Может знаете эту проблему?