# Как получить название выделенного файла в качестве аргумента в батфайле(командной строке)

Tags: cmd, powershell, bat

Суть в том, чтобы бат файл выполнялся по отношению к выделенным в проводнике windows файлам.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028832/ - не подойдёт?